# MultiSelectList SelectedValues, not working in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox, viewbag

Debugging I get this:
[image]

So, User_SportsList is a MultiSelectList with the proper Items and the proper SelectedValues.

I pass to the view like this:

```
ViewBag.usl = User_SportsList;
```

In my View I have this:

```
@Html.ListBox("UserSports", ViewBag.usl as MultiSelectList)
```

And is showing the list with all the items, but SelectedValues aren't working. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "SelectedValues aren't working"?  Do you mean on the postback to the controller, or in the rendered HTML?

Comment: In the rendered HTML, in the listbox "karts" and "fishing" must appear selected, but are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *SelectedValues* property needs to contain an array of values (where "value" is defined by *DataValueField*), and not the items themselves.  So, in this example, you should set SelectedValues equal to:

```
User_SportsList.SelectedValues = new [] { 3, 4 };
```

Comment: That's it ! but with: User_SportsList.SelectedValues = new[] { 3, 4 }; you get an "property or index cannot be assigned to -- is readonly" so I need to do it like that: MultiSelectList User_SportsList = new MultiSelectList(allSports, "SportId", "Name", new [] {3,4}); But you are right dbaseman, thanks!